# Party wall construction in Ewardian house

Tags: drywall, insulation, fireproof

I have a brick party wall between my house and my neighbors and we need to build a fire retardant wall above the bricks in the eaves of the building.

As far as I have understood building regs here in the UK, 2 x 12mm fireproof plasterboard is permitted in the roof space. with insulation in between.  I think that wooden battens are permitted also as the rafters are wooden.  Can the party wall go up and have cutouts for the rafters or does the whole attic area need plasterboarding also ?

Any guidance / corrections to my understanding are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Have you contacted your local council to double check your understanding? I'm sure they'll be happy to work with you to ensure this is done correctly.

Comment: No I haven't but good suggestion.  Thanks